# Create excel csv files with all computers of each Listed OU

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory, ldap

```
$OUpath = @(
  "OU=example,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=exam.ple,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example1,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example2,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example3,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example4,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example5,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example6,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example7,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example8,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example9,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=CA,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=CAB,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=Ara,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=Gil,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=Kbi,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=Cieux,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=liz,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=mes,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=IO,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=SE,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=SC,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix")

foreach ($i in $OUpath){

$fname= $i.Substring(3,9) + ".csv"
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * -SearchBase $i.toString() | 
Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion | 
Export-CSV $fname -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
}
```

**Remark**: OU=exam.ple with $fname= $i.Substring(3,9) + ".csv" gives not an excel csv file because of the dot in the ou name.
**Question**: Is it possible to generate 1 excel file with different workSheets ? And transform the data directly into excel tables ?

Comment: so your ACTUAL Question is how to get a valid file name from the OU list you posted? if so ... please post the result you want for each of the input list items.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. Things of importance deserve names, Nikso. While helpful naming is not the easiest part from modelling to coding, having no name at all (literals) is no help at all, giving rise to depreciative names like *naked constants* or *magic numbers*: What significance are `3` and `9`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey My question was if it is possible to get the results in excel worksheets in stead of generating multiple excel files. The code is actually working. It generates the excel files except for the one with the dot in the ou name where it generates another strange file type. I just had to delete the dot manually to fix it. For the output I want to regroup all the returned computers in one excel file, separated in different excel worksheets. Thank you for your advice, kind regards.

Comment: @greybeard It is the position of the character in the string. It begins on position 3 of the string and ends on position 9 of the string, and set the result as file name.
Thanks you for your advice :)

Comment: @JosefZ The link you shared helped me a lot, it brought a solution to my problem. The solution for the file names is working also ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Please feel free [to self-answer your question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) (and accept it later as well).

Comment: The second parameter for `.Substring()` is the specified **length**, not the ending position. Also, if you only want 3 properties, don't do `-Property *`, but just ask for the properties that aren't returned by default, like `Name`. Using the asteriks will have the cmdlet gather **all** properties which is time and memory consuming.

Answer (score 1):

```
$OUpath = @("OU=example,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=exam.ple,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example1,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example2,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example3,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example4,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example5,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example6,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example7,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example8,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=example9,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=CA,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=CAB,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=Ara,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=Gil,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=Kbi,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=Cieux,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=liz,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=mes,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=IO,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=SE,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix",
  "OU=SC,OU=Parent OU,DC=domain name,DC=domain prefix")

foreach ($distinguishedName in $OUpath)
{
$csvFileName = ($distinguishedName -replace "OU","" -replace "=","" -replace ",","" -replace "Parent","" -replace "DC","" -replace "domain name","" -replace "prefix","") +".csv"


Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion -SearchBase $i.toString() | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion | Export-CSV $csvFileName -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
  
}

Function Merge-CSVFiles
{
Param(
$CSVPath = "C:\Users\Haddouch_Fadil\excelSource",
$XLOutput="C:\Users\Haddouch_Fadil\exceloutput\temp.xls" 
)

$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem ("$CSVPath\*") -Include *.csv
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.sheetsInNewWorkbook = $csvFiles.Count
$workbooks = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$CSVSheet = 1

Foreach ($CSV in $Csvfiles){

$worksheets = $workbooks.worksheets
$CSVFullPath = $CSV.FullName
$SheetName = ($CSV.name -split "\.")[0]
$worksheet = $worksheets.Item($CSVSheet)
$worksheet.Name = $SheetName
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $CSVFullPath)
$CellRef = $worksheet.Range("A1")
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$CellRef)
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).TextFileCommaDelimiter = $True
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).TextFileParseType  = 1
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).Refresh()
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).delete()
$worksheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
$CSVSheet++

}

$workbooks.SaveAs($XLOutput,51)
$workbooks.Saved = $true
$workbooks.Close()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbooks) | Out-Null
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

}

Merge-CSVFiles -CSVPath C:\Users\Haddouch_Fadil\excelSource -XLOutput C:\Users\Haddouch_Fadil\exceloutput\temp.xls

Remove-Item * -Include *.csv
```

This is my final code.

- The script returns all the computer objects inside a OU. It searches with the distinguished name of the OU's placed in the list.
- Generating .csv files with this information for each OU; with the correct output for the file names. (Deleted all the repetitive stuff in the distinguished name of the OU's) This was important in order to create the worksheets with the right name. Otherwise I had to do it manually.
- Convert all csv files into tables and put them in different worksheets in 1 excel file with the call of the Merge-CSVFiles function.

-Deletes generated csv files at the end in the current PowerShell directory

-> My next step is to transform the tables in the worksheets into data tables in Excel with a VB script.